# Combine a list of tuples and regular list into dictionary then sum by unique value of tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have 2 lists: a list of tuples and list of integers. They both have the same length. I want to combine them into a dictionary and sum the value integer for the same tuple.

```
a_list = [('orange','banana'),('grape','apple'),('cucumber','tomatoes'),('orange','banana'),('grape','apple'),('grape','apple')]
b_list = [6,10,12,8,1,5]
```

Expected output:

```
new_dict = {('orange','banana'):14,('grape','apple'):16,('cucumber',tomatoes'):12}
```

It doesn't work when I try to combine them using `dict(zip(a_list, b_list))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for this:

```
a_list = [('orange', 'banana'), ('grape', 'apple'), ('cucumber', 'tomatoes'), ('orange', 'banana'), ('grape', 'apple'), ('grape', 'apple')]
b_list = [6, 10, 12, 8, 1, 5]

from collections import defaultdict

new_dict = defaultdict(int)

for a, b in zip(a_list, b_list):
  new_dict[a] += b

print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>,
 {('orange', 'banana'): 14,
  ('grape', 'apple'): 16,
  ('cucumber', 'tomatoes'): 12}
)
```

Comment: Can you help me understand why the sum in dict(zip(a_list,b_list)) is incorrect?

Comment: @user11666514 dictionaries have unique keys, so when you try to create a dict using `zip` (which has tuples with the same keys), it will only keep the last values for those repeating keys.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with just the basics:

```
for a,b in zip(a_list,b_list):
    try:
        d[a]+=b
    except:
        d.update({a:b})
```

output:

```
{('orange', 'banana'): 14, ('grape', 'apple'): 16, ('cucumber', 'tomatoes'): 12}
```

the try will fail until all the keys have been updated, then after it will start summing the next values to the keys

Comment: You can use `d[a] = b` instead of `d.update({a:b})`.

Comment: granted that is easier to remember :D is there a big difference?

Comment: I suppose there's no difference since they both will add a key/value pair if the key doesn't exist and will overwrite the old value with the new one if the key exists.